# How to chain several ORM relationships in Kohana 3?

Tags: php, orm, kohana-3

fairly simple question I think that I couldn't find the answer to in the docs (http://kohanaframework.org/guide/orm/relationships)

I have the need to define relationships with several **Models** (in bold) (each has a corresponding table) at once, if that makes sense.

I have several models that have slightly intertwined relationships.

the **connection** model `$_belongs_to` the **user**. This code works fine, great. But the connection also needs to `$_has_one` **song** (i can haz cheezeburger??), and to `$has_one` **keyword**, if that makes sense.

This is because I want to access the **song** name and **keyword** name through the connection, for instance using `$connection->song->name`, and then $`connection->keyword->name`...

SO, the problem is I can't seem to chain the relationships detailed above, as I can only declare one relationship per model.... so how do I do this? Or maybe there's another much easier way of doing it that I'm unaware of...

I presume I'm being a n00b and would love some help on this. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collect relationships in arrays:

```
class Model_Connection extends ORM {

   protected $_belongs_to = array(
      'user' => array(), 
   );

   protected $_has_one = array(
      'song' => array(),
      'keyword' => array(),
   );

}
```

PS. But it seems like both `song` and `keyword` must be in a `$_belongs_to` property (one `song` has many `connections`, one `connection` belongs to `song`).

Comment: thanks, although for others' reference, you have to use the correct notation including the blank array after, so  protected $_belongs_to = array(
  'user'=> array(),
 );